# Why am I getting a "Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null" error with Knockout JS?

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, mvvm, knockout.js

Today is the first day for me in Knockout . Got struck with it . Below is my first sample code using knockout.js and it shows an error .

> Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null

Here is my script:`

```
   function ViewModel()  
   {  
     var self = this;  
     self.n1 = ko.observable(10);  
     self.n2 = ko.observable(10);  
     self.n3 = ko.observable(10);  
   }  
   ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());  `
```

Here is my html:

```
<body>
<p>Number1:<input data-bind="value:n1"></input></p>
<p>Number2:<input data-bind="value:n2"></input></p>
<p>Number3:<input data-bind="value:n3"></input></p>
</body>
```

I want to know the reason for the above error and how to overcome it...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you set up your code like this, it'll work.

```
<body>
<p>Number1:<input data-bind="value:n1"></p>
<p>Number2:<input data-bind="value:n2"></p>
<p>Number3:<input data-bind="value:n3"></p>
<script src="knockout.js"></script>
<script>

function ViewModel() {  
   var self = this;  
   self.n1 = ko.observable(10);  
   self.n2 = ko.observable(10);  
   self.n3 = ko.observable(10);
}  

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());  `

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: HTML is parsed top-to-bottom.  So, if you include the scripts at the top of the page (e.g. `<head>` section), they could be run before some or all page elements are ready to be interacted with.  There are other ways to do it (responding to DOM ready events), but putting the code at the bottom does the same.

Comment: One other tip: `<input>` elements don't have a closing tag.  In html you just write them like `<input type="text">` or `<input type="text"/>` in XHTML.

Answer (score 36):

If you want to keep your `<script>` at the top of the page, you can use jQuery's ready() function to delay the initialization until the page has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

Comment: I don't know whether it works ... Anyway thank you for your valuable answer ...!!!

Comment: Yes, it works. I had the same bug as you and this page helped me to solve it with $.ready().

Answer (score 1):

I think ko.applyBindings(obj); should be write under view model.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>KO Examples</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.1.0.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var  obj = {
            first_name : 'Gazal Irish'
        };


    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>My name : <span data-bind="text: first_name"></span>
<p> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    ko.applyBindings(obj);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```