# Simple, basic knockout typescript example

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, typescript

I just want to get a simple typescript knockout example working. I have used nugget to get the typescript knockout and have downloaded knockout 3.0.0 js. Here is my typescript file

```
declare var ko;

class AppViewModel {
    firstName = ko.observable("Bob");
    lastName = ko.observable("Newhart");
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Here is my html

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js'></script>
    <script src="AppViewModel.js"></script>     
</head>
<body>
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I referencing the knockout library correctly? Am I calling ko.applyBindings correctly?

For completeness, here is the generated javascript

```
var AppViewModel = (function () {
    function AppViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("Bob");
        this.lastName = ko.observable("Newhart");
    }
    return AppViewModel;
})();

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
//# sourceMappingURL=AppViewModel.js.map
```

Comment: @Philip Scott Givens - Yes. You are doing it right. Here is a working fiddle of your code http://jsfiddle.net/mfVT5/ .Are you seeing any errors? Have you verified that the source HTML in your browser contains all the javascript?

Comment: "Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null" in the knockout js from when I call ko.applyBindings

Comment: @user1, what does the "onLoad" mean in jsfiddle.net? Should I be using an "onLoad" in the code that I provided?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15090080/1226612

I moved my script tag to the end of the file.

Comment: @Philip Scott Givens - Glad you have it fixed. Looks like your script was executing before the DOM was loaded. If you are using Jquery, you could wrap your call to ko.applyBindings inside the $( document ).ready() function.